# Flask route missing arguments that already given

Tags: flask, routes

I am trying to call the following route:

```
@bp.route("/notify/<user_id>/<title>/<message>",
methods=["POST"])
def trigger_notification(user_id, title, message):
    data = request.get_json() or {}
    # do_somthing_by_data
```

I called the route by [httpie](https://httpie.io):

```
http POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/notify/b2bbbf67956c3db9/title/message_txt
```

But I got the following errors:

```
TypeError: notify() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'user_id', 'title', and 'message'
```

Comment: The name of the function for your route is `trigger_notification` but, you're getting the error on a function named `notify`. Where are you defining `notify` and where are you calling it?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context on the code example, please? I guess something elsewhere triggers that error

Comment: Thanks @MattKeane & @tsamaya, Your comments really help. The error was in `data` variable which was empty dict in my call. the correct call is `http POST url user_id=user_id title=title message=my_message`. or refactoring the route function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example works fine on my side:

Using Flask v1.1.2.

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/notify/<user_id>/<title>/<message>", methods=["POST"])
def trigger_notification(user_id, title, message):
    print ("{} {} {}".format(user_id, title, message))
    data = request.get_json() or {}
    return data
```

Tested with

```sh
curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/notify/user/title/message \
    -d '{"body":"some data"}' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

It outputs

```sh
                                                                                                    
(65050335) ➜  65050335 flask run
 * Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
user title message
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2020 14:11:30] "POST /notify/user/title/message HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and it returns

```sh
{"body":"some data"}
```